# How to format \thesection with leading 0?

Tags: luatex, fancyhdr

I'm pulling together a design from a graphic artist's ideas.. In the body the section header does not show numbers, but they want the section number in the header - but as a padded number - so not "Section 1" but as "Section 01".. of course `\thesection` is a real integer - is there a way to pad the number with a leading 0?

[image]

Comment: What about the formatting of the section numbers in the table of contents (also bookmarks) and in references (`\ref`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So digging around on ctan I found [numprint](https://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/numprint/numprint.pdf)

Inserting the section details is the usual \leftmark thing from fancyhdr, but defining the mark looks like:

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
    \nplpadding{2}%
    \markboth{Section \numprint{\thesection} \newline#1}{}}
```

Giving you (yes I left numbering on for the body section title):
[image]

Hope this helps someone in the future :)

Answer (score 2):

If the section number should always have at least two digits (including in the table of contents, bookmarks, references, ...), then `\thesection` should be redefined accordingly:

```
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{%
  \ifnum\value{section}<10 0\fi % pad with zero if necessary
  \arabic{section}% print the section number
}
```

---

### Remarks to the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/631068/16967)

(too long for a comment)

The answer uses:

```
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
    \nplpadding{2}%
    \markboth{Section \numprint{\thesection} \newline#1}{}}
```

The problems:

- `\markboth` is a command with moving arguments that will be used at a later time at shipout time. This decouples the formatting command `\nplpadding` from its application in `\numprint`. Thus, each `\nplpadding` *after* the `\section` command and before the page shipout will change the formatting settings.
- `\thesection` can expand to a plain number that is needed by `\numprint`. The default is using `\arabic`/`\@arabic` that is a formatting command that can be redefined (e.g. to switch to the appropriate font, ...) and it is therefore not guaranteed to expand to a plain number. The safe way is `\the\value{section}` or `\number\value{section}`, for example.

Suggestion:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{numprint}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\PrintThePaddedNumber}[1]{%
  \begingroup  % The group keeps the formatting changes local.
    \nplpadding{2}%
    \numprint{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
  % * \the\value{section} is expandable and
  %   is expanded at the execution of \markboth.
  % * \PrintThePaddedNumber is expanded later, when the header
  %   line is set.
  \markboth{Section \PrintThePaddedNumber{\the\value{section}}\newline#1}{}%
}

\begin{document}
\section{First section}
The code number of James Bond is \nplpadding{3}\numprint{7}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: No, the actual section number should not be shown as in the question.. but the page header should contain the section with a padded number.

Comment: @baradhili If the section number is *not* shown, then its padding does not matter.

Comment: @baradhili I have added some remarks to your answer here (too long for a comment).